# How to make a regular Expression for name Validation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, regex, xcode

I want to make a regular expression in which user can only enter alphabets.

I am using this piece of code to validate the `UITextField`.

I am validating the code in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method.

```
 NSString *regex = @"[a-zA-Z]";
NSPredicate *testRegex = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

if(![testRegex evaluateWithObject:string])
    return NO;
```

It is working fine but I can not delete using `BacKspace` button As my `RegEx` doesn't allow this.

How can I make a regular expression which supports alphabets and allow deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)iRange replacementString:(NSString *)iText {
    NSString *newString = [iTextView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:iRange withString:iText];
    NSString *abnRegex = @"[A-Za-z]+";
    NSPredicate *abnTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", abnRegex];
    return ([abnTest evaluateWithObject:newString] || newString.length == 0);
}
```

Comment: `iText` is nothing but `string`. I like to prefix method parameters with `i`. Changed my post to reflect it in the method signature.

Comment: yes thanx for it...it works ... will you please provide some explaination also :)

Comment: You are most welcome! Well - I thought code speaks for itself. Idea here is to get the newly added string and pass it though the regular expression. That was one major thing missing in your code. That handled, the only thing left to handle the last character deletion which would result in empty string as new character. Thats covered right side of || condition. Hope it make sense!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this (Just a work around) :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (range.length > 0)
    {
         // We're deleting
         return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        // We're adding
        NSString *regex = @"[a-zA-Z]";
        NSPredicate *testRegex = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

       if(![testRegex evaluateWithObject:string])
           return NO;
       else
           return YES;        
}
```

Comment: . this is working..but could you please explain the mechanism behind this

Comment: refer : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: